# Install NodeJS specific version on Alpine Linux via APK

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

On Ubuntu based systems we can run the install script like this

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

however on Alpine linux, the debian based install script won't work

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apk add -y nodejs
```

Node LTS are v14 and v16, i can't find any official packages.

How can you install a specific node version (v15.14) in your docker container?